# Error trying to get metadata from url stream using java/android

Tags: java, android, metadata, audio-streaming, mediametadataretriever

I am getting no values while trying to get the metadata from a URL stream.

```
String url;
        FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        url = "http://stream.radiojar.com/rxmkwt2p5tzuv";
        mmr.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
        mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
        mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        //String all = mmr.toString();
        Log.i("metadata",mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
```

I get error java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message.
this is because the String is empty.
If I try

```
String all = mmr.toString();
        Log.i("metadata",all);
```

my println gives me

```
I/metadata: wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever@fd7a190
```

Any ideas? I have tried with various different streams but all give the same result except different letters/numbers after @.

Comment: I am the develop of this library. `mmr.toString()` won't print metadata, it prints out the object you created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library and how `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever#extractMetadata` works. I suspect that the second call to `mmr.extractMetadata()` is `null` because it has been "extracted" already three lines above.

Comment: Thats not it im afraid, even if I only use the method once it has the same result.

Comment: Ok, then your URL does not provide any metadata for `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM`, most likely. The `mmr` is not null and the value returned from `mmr.extractMetadata()` is null, therefore it must be something like this.

Comment: Or maybe you are missing out on some method like `mmr.startDataSourceConnection()` or `mmr.open()` to establish a connection to the URL before extracting the metadata. Usually, in this case, calls to `extractMetadata()` would produce an error and since this is a third party library seemingly produced by one private person, there might not be an error thrown and the method simply returns null.

Comment: I don’t see any methods like that, I don’t think it has anything like that. Also apparently the file does have metadata, I just can’t get to it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will print out the metadata you are requesting, if it exists:

```
String url = "http://stream.radiojar.com/rxmkwt2p5tzuv";

FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
String album = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);            

if (album != null) {    
    Log.i("album", album);
}

if (artist != null) {    
    Log.i("artist", artist);
}

mmr.release();
```